# Configure ignore dirs on helm-locate

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-helm

```
M-x helm-locate
```

lists files in hidden folders, that i will never open. How to instruct helm not to look into certain directories for file search & open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`helm-locate` uses linux command `locate` which uses updatedb to index the file location. To ignore some directories, configure /etc/updatedb.conf as

```
PRUNEPATHS="EXISTINGPATH NEWPATH"
```

And run `updatedb` in shell prompt with sudo permissions to get this change reflected.